# Creating map tiles on WP8?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, dictionary, bing-maps

I have been using the Google Maps API for quite some time for an interactive radar map, but am now working on this for Windows Phone. Running into quite a few issues converting this JS code into working map tiles for a WP8 map control...

Can someone help me here? I know this HTML is of no use, but just want to know where to start. Things that exist in the google maps API such as map X,Y, (Of the 256x256 tile grid) etc don't seem to exist at all into the windows phone map control. This is the main problem I am having...

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Atmosphere Backend</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

    tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
        return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime();
    },

    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    opacity:0.50,
    name : 'NEXRAD',
    isPng: true
});


  map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you'd like to add background tracking (GPS) to your app, you should shy away from WP8.1 for now. This is only supported in WP8 at this time, which you seem to be going for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started you can find some documentation on Maps in Windows Phone 8 here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207045%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) It should be noted that Windows Phone 8.1 uses a new/different map control from WP8.

To get started you can add a map to a page in Windows Phone 8 like so.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SpatialDataViewer.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <m:Map Name="MyMap"/>  
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Next expand the properties section of the project and open the WMAppMainiifest file. Open the Capabilities tab and check ID_CAP_MAP.

You can add a tile layer to this map from code like so:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            MyMap.Loaded += (s, e) =>
            {
                string tileURL = "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/{zoomLevel}/{x}/{y}.png?" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                MyMap.TileSources.Add(new TileSource(tileURL));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation on the TileSource class can be found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You can also find documentation on the UriFormat that you can use here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource.uriformat(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource.uriformat%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, this is much simpler then the gmaps API. Nice to know that the x,y,zoomlevel properties are there and doesn't require calculations as I feared.